# Integer overflow in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm having trouble with, what I believe is an integer overflow problem.

I'm trying to set an `Int` initial value to 5,000,000,000 but when I load the app it shows as 705,032,704

I'll likely need numbers up to 99 billion, is there a way to avoid the overflow?

Comment: Try Int64, or UInt64: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/NumericTypes.html

Comment: The `Int` type can easily handle numbers that size. How are you displaying that value?

Comment: int64 solved the issue.  - Nate Cook: it's being displayed in a label.text I had the same result with and without NSNumberFormatter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For certain Value and type of Int are here use accordingly

- Int8   -128  ||||  127
- Int16
  -32,768  ||||  32,767
- Int32
  -2,147,483,648 |||| 2,147,483,647
- Int64
  -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 |||| 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
- UInt8 0 255
- UInt16 0 65,535
- UInt32 0 4,294,967,295
- UInt64 0 18,446,744,073,709,551,615